# What were vehicles and society in general powered by in Avatar LOK

Tags: the-legend-of-korra

One of the things I found striking in the Legend of Korra was how society went from what was essentially a pre-industrial society (with minor exceptions) with some use of bending, to a society which was *roughly* at par with the 1920s.

There's references to Mako working at a power generator full of fire benders firing lightning (which would indicate society was basically powered by human batteries ), but Tarrlok blew up a boat with a equalist hand taser thing, and the design of most vehicles, and their use by non benders suggested ICE/ECE engines.

What was used to power LOK era society?

Comment: Mako is not an energy bender (those are extremely rare), he's a fire bender who is able to generate lightning (which is relatively common).

Comment: Relatively - there was *one* we see in TLA, and a roomful in LOK. Anyway, corrected that

Comment: According to [the wiki](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Motor_vehicle), vehicles were powered by gasoline, but I can't find a good reference confirming that.

Comment: The sound of the engines of the various cars and trucks are the same sound as gasoline engines, indicating that they aren't battery (i.e. firebender) powered.  I think in the absence of any signs to the contrary, we can assume they were powered the same as in our world, with the addition of firebender lightning-generation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to the introduction of the [Satomobile](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Satomobile), most vehicles in the Avatar-verse were powered by steam, either using coal or, if driven by a firebender, bent fire as a power source.

The Satomobile wasn't the first vehicle to use gasoline as a power source, but it was the vehicle that popularised the idea and immediately provoked a wide range of knock-offs.

> Prior to Satomobiles, engines relied on steam and mainly powered
> mechanized drills and tanks, but they were inefficient and unsuitable
> for small-scale use. **Hiroshi Sato was the first person to popularize a
> gasoline-powered engine capable of transporting a driver and several
> passengers in a carriage over long distances**, and in a way that was
> affordable to the average customer.
>
> Satomobiles quickly became a
> must-have vehicle. With demand so high, Cabbage Corp created the
> Cabbage Car, a lower-cost compact car.
>
> <sub><sup>[Welcome to Republic City - Interactive Game](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Welcome_to_Republic_City_(game))</sup></sub>